# padding right and bottom gone on fixed element

Tags: css

I have a div `.modal` that has a fixed position with `padding: 90px;`. There is a div `.child` inside it with `height: 1500px;`.

The problem is that the padding right and bottom gone on `modal`, I have tried to set `box-sizing: border-box;` but it cannot solve the problem.

If you inspect it, there are negative value applied on position, I don't know why.

```css
.modal {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}

.child {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Padding should be present no matter the value of the height of the content.

Comment: because the .child has ab long height. reduce the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Try this

Comment: As you can guess from the class name, it's a modal...The position has to be fixed...

Comment: @doqgmui check I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you, so basically the padding top and bottom didn't show because the child div was taking the whole height of the page but if you set the height to be for example 800px then it will work.

```css
.modal {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.child {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```